# Caching prepared statements in the SQLite Tcl Interface

Tags: sqlite, tcl

This question concerns coding properly in Tcl to best take advantage of SQLite's resetting of prepared statements rather than finalizing them.

Is there any difference, in regards to caching prepared statements, between code like

```
set ::SQL::QueryName { update ... }
dbcmd eval $::SQL::QueryName
```

and

```
dbcmd eval { update ...}
```

Or is it simply: in whatever manner the SQL string gets passed to SQLite, it'll store the last 10 or whatever value is set in `dbcmd cache size N` up to a maximum of 100?

Is there anything the coder can/should do to assist SQLite in this area?

Thank you for considering my question.

I forgot I should have added to this question, how does using the `:` symbol binding parameters affect caching? For example, if two queries are identical except for in a WHERE clause like `data_key = :starKey` versus `data_key = :endKey`, will these be considered one or two queries for caching purposes?

It could be written `data_key = :dataKey` and just `set dataKey $startKey` or `set dataKey $endKey` before executing the query.

Is there somewhere that this kind of information is listed? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need to take any special steps to cache prepared statements in the Tcl interface to SQLite. The interface library manages such a cache (with an LRU expiration rule) for you behind the scenes already (using the literal text of the SQL as its key). You can control the number of statements cached via the `cache` method of the connection; it defaults to being of size 10 and can be set to hold up to 100 statements.

```
db cache size 25
db eval { ... }
```

(I've never personally had the need to explicitly set the cache size.)

This is a really common aspect in how Tcl works: transparent caches where relevant (with the usual locus of the cache being inside the value instance, though not so in `tclsqlite`). It means that many programs end up storing cached compilations of things, either indexed by or attached to their literal, and all without any special action by user code. (Regular expressions cache this way, and so too do most evaluated script fragments.)

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to be a pest but, in regards to the last part of my  question, does a different `:varName` make two prepared statements different, or does SQLite treat them as `?` as in the C API? In other words, if I want to use the same query many times but bound to a different Tcl `:varName`, will SQLite cache them as different statements because the strings passed in `db eval{}` are different? Thank you.

Comment: I've just checked the [source code](https://sqlite.org/src/file?name=src/tclsqlite.c&ci=trunk) and there is definitely an LRU cache (which will be per-connection) and it is indexed by the *literal form* of the SQL (i.e., it uses `memcmp()` on the bytes of the string to test for equality); changing a bound variable name will change which cache entry it is. The `cache` method of the connection can be used to control it. It defaults to caching the last 10 statements, and can be set to any size up to 100.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize. I certainly didn't mean to be so pushy as to ask you to look something up. I thought perhaps you just happened to know the answer. When you know only a little, as I do, you tend to think everyone else knows it all. Please forgive me. Thanks for the link also. I didn't know it was so easy to view the code like that (though I should have) and reading it reveals that I know even less than I thought.